# How do I include an interval to prevent 'too many requests' error in for-loop (+ 2 minor questions)?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm currently in the data preparation phase of my master thesis and I've ran into a problem. I'm trying to scrape a website using a for loop and the rvest package in RStudio, based on a vector of ~90k IDs. **How do I add a time interval in the for loop to prevent the HTML - too many requests error?**

I've also got two minor side problems I need some help with:

1. If I only use a vector of 10 IDs to test the loop, the loop keeps overwriting the result so that observations 1-9 are overwritten and it only shows observation 10.
2. I can successfully scrape one element (first name) but the code fails when I try to scrape a second element and add it in another column.

I've been tinkering with the code for a while so I've already had many iterations of it and this is the only version that I got to work. For the overwriting of the observations I've tried adding [i] after 'playernames' but it produces the error 'new columns would leave holes after existing columns'.

```
# playerid is a vector of ~90k different IDs. (wouldn't work as a list)
# I successfully manage to scrape the first name of the player, although it keeps overwriting the observation.

for(i in playerid){
  websiteX <- paste("http://www.X.com/id=",i, sep="")
  websiteX <- read_html(websiteX)
  playernames <- data.frame(first =websiteX %>% html_node("dd:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text() ,
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  playernames$playerid <- i
}

# I want to also scrape the surname using: sur =websiteX %>% html_node(websiteX, "dd:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text() ,
```

In short, what I want is a data frame of the 90k player IDs, followed by a column for the first name and a column for the second name.

What I'm getting is an HTML overload error if I use the entire set of 90k IDs and only trying to scrape the first name. If I only scrape a few names (say 10), it keeps overwriting the observation.

I have found no way to implement the scraping of the surname, nor do I understand how to add a time interval to prevent the overload error.

```
# Changing 
playernames <- data.frame~... 
# to 
playernames[i] <- data.frame~... 
# produces the new columns would leave holes after existing columns error.
```

Comment: I don't do much web scraping, but would adding `Sys.sleep(<some positive number>)` into your code help with the time interval problem?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it with:  
date_time<-Sys.time()
  while((as.numeric(Sys.time()) - as.numeric(date_time))<1){}